# Resizing table view height due to SDWebImage image height

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm using Swift 4, and I want to get online image and resize table view cell height and table view height due to height of these online images. I'm using `SDWebImage` to show online images, this is the code:

```
var images = ["http://styliee.com/images/products/6d9vH1Kk2r.jpeg","http://styliee.com/images/products/6d9vH1Kk2r.jpeg"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductImageTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductImageTableViewCell

    let imageUrl = URLs.productImageUrl + self.product.images[indexPath.row].name
    cell.adImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl))
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.layoutSubviews()
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

but it doesn't work as it should,
any help?

Comment: if you are getting images from backend get the ratio of the image from backend and adjust height of the tableview cell according to the ratio

Comment: kindly show the constraints of your imageView

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This

@IBOutlet var tablViewHight : NSLayoutConstraint!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imgCell", for: indexPath) as! imgCell

        if let image = UIImage(named:"6d9vH1Kk2r.jpeg") {

            let ratio = image.size.height / image.size.width

            // Make the frame the right size to show the thumbnail
            let cellFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.contentSize.width, height: tableView.contentSize.width * ratio)
            let imageView = cell.imgShow // image view constraints pin all edges to the cell edges
            imageView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView?.image = image

            tablViewHight.constant = cellFrame.height
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```